# Fetching mails into postfix/dovecot via pop3/imap

Tags: linux, debian, email, postfix, dovecot

I managed to set up my first Debian mail server using postfix and dovecot. I use roundcube to access my IMAP accounts which are defined by virtual users in a MySQL data base.

Everything works perfectly so far. What I want to do now is fetching mails from other servers (like hotmail for example) and distribute them to according virtual accounts.

Since I have absolutely no idea where to start here I thought I'd give it a try and just aks for a general direction.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want a tool like [fetchmail](http://www.fetchmail.info/) or getmail. They pick up mail via POP/IMAP and insert them into the local mail system.

You use fetchmail with a config file, usually called `.fetchmailrc` like this:

```
poll mail.example.com protocol pop3:
     username "admin" password "dir3cti0n" is "squire" here;
     username "fore" password "0rd3r" is "foreman" here;
```

The `is squire` here does the mapping from the remote address to the local one.

(Example pulled from [here](https://www.linode.com/docs/email/clients/using-fetchmail-to-retrieve-email/))

Comment: I've looked into fetchmail already, which seems like a great tool, but how would I do the mapping to the virtual mail users on my server? All the examples I saw used existing users on the server.

Comment: See my edit for an example.

Comment: so the 'is "something"' can be a virtual user too?

Comment: Yes, that's not a problem.

Comment: Oh god, well I guess could have just tried that. Thank you so much.